# Get specific words from string c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I am working on a final year project. I have a file that contain some text. I need to get words form this file that contain "//jj" tag. e.g abc//jj, bcd//jj etc.

suppose file is containing the following text

> ffafa adada//bb adad ssss//jj aad adad adadad aaada   dsdsd//jj 
>   dsdsd sfsfhf//vv
>   dfdfdf

I need all the words that are associated with //jj tag. I am stuck here past few days.
My code that i am trying

```
  // Create OpenFileDialog
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter for file extension and default file extension
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

        // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox
        string filename = string.Empty;
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document
            filename = dlg.FileName;
            FileNameTextBox.Text = filename;
        }

        string text;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        string FilteredText = string.Empty;

        string pattern = @"(?<before>\w+) //jj (?<after>\w+)";

        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            FilteredText="before:" + matches[i].Groups["before"].ToString();
            //Console.WriteLine("after:" + matches[i].Groups["after"].ToString());
        }

        textbx.Text = FilteredText;
```

I cant find my result please help me.

Comment: Before I try to help with this, can I just ask you to confirm that the requirements of the project allow you to ask for help from outside sources like SO?

Comment: What is your code producing as is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `LINQ` you could do this with one line:

```
string[] taggedwords = input.Split(' ').Where(x => x.EndsWith(@"//jj")).ToArray();
```

And all your //jj words will be there...

Comment: Nice! You've reminded me to go and read my "LINQ for Dummies" book again ;-)

Comment: I just mean I'm jealous that it didn't occur to me to use LINQ as I've been learning to use it recently :-)

Comment: @Equalsk ah, I see.. ;) so that is what you mean. lol, no worries I will still vote your answer up then. :D This way, you won't feel your answer go wasted. :) your answer is actually easier to understand for new programmer than LINQ. I mean: it is still a nice answer. :D

Comment: much helpful. Thanks

Comment: I have stuck again because text that I have in the file is in other languages like Urdu and Arabic, Not in English, In both of your code failed to get specific words because it can't split

Comment: It is pretty hard to understand your situation. But maybe you can post a new question with the new set of texts and new set of attempts made. Depending on the new case, maybe it is best to use use same/similar/different ways to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think Regex is overkill if that's definitely how the string will look. You haven't specified that you definitely need to use Regex so why not try this instead?

```
// A list that will hold the words ending with '//jj'
List<string> results = new List<string>();

// The text you provided
string input = @"ffafa adada//bb adad ssss//jj aad adad adadad aaada dsdsd//jj dsdsd sfsfhf//vv dfdfdf";

// Split the string on the space character to get each word
string[] words = input.Split(' ');

// Loop through each word
foreach (string word in words)
{
    // Does it end with '//jj'?
    if(word.EndsWith(@"//jj"))
    {
        // Yes, add to the list
        results.Add(word);
    }
}

// Show the results
foreach(string result in results)
{
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

Results are:

> ssss//jj
>   dsdsd//jj

Obviously this is not quite as robust as a regex, but you didn't provide any more detail for me to go on.

Comment: In how far is Regex overkill?

Comment: Because it's complex to read and understand unless you know what you're doing, which it seems OP does not. The above code is more of a beginners approach to get the same results and is much easier to understand, IMHO. I'm not saying Regex is slower, if that's what you mean.

Comment: My solution was similar but using Linq to get the same result _results = words.Where(s => s.Trim().EndsWith(@"//jj")).ToArray();_

Comment: I love a good bit of LINQ, I just wanted to keep it nice and simple because, well, I'm simple!

Comment: I have stuck again because text that I have in the file is in other languages like Urdu and Arabic, Not in English, In both of your code failed to  get specific words because it can't split.

Comment: Well then you should have been more clear and put that information in your question...

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra space in your regex, it assumes there's a space before "//jj". What you want is:

```
 string pattern = @"(?<before>\w+)//jj (?<after>\w+)";
```

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will yield the words you are looking for:

```
string pattern = "(\\S*)\\/\\/jj"
```

A bit nicer without backslash escaping:

```
(\S*)\/\/jj
```

Matches will include the `//jj` but you can get the word from the first bracketed group.

Comment: If `abc abc//ss abc//gg //jj` should return 0 matches then `(\w+)\/\/jj` works also.